# How to add < to "allowed values list"?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to add:
1|small (<100)
2|etc ...

but it will only display "small (" as the first option.
I've tried < without success.
Any way to display the < ?

Comment: Have you tried using &lt; instead of < ?

Comment: I did - it just converted the &lt; to < in the above text ;-)

Comment: I am afraid you have to write "less than" unless you override the output.

Comment: @Clive I think he just meant he tried and it didn't work, because it actually doesn't.

Comment: I guess I can live with "less than" ;-)

Comment: A workaround would be to use a taxonomy term reference instead of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Both `<`, `&lt;` and also `&#60;` works with a checkbox/radio widget. `<select>` doesn't allow html code for options.

In consecuence Drupal strip tags if the `<select>` widget is configured. This is done in [_options_prepare_options()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!options!options.module/function/_options_prepare_options/7).

Short story: after some tests I've found that `small (< 100)` works (there's a whitespace between `<` and `100`), so it is not considered a tag.

I've done my tests with:

```
drush php-eval 'print strip_tags("small (< 100)") ."\n"'
```

Comment: I'm afraid this just isn't true. Put `<select><option value="lt100">&lt; 100</option></select>` in an HTML file and see what happens...

Comment: Ops.. you're right. I did some tests with valid html, instead of just `<`. I've found that Drupal does `check_plain()` to the values: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_select_options/7

Comment: Updated the answer. Problem is not at `check_plain()` but `strip_tags()`

Answer (score 2):

This is infact possible by overriding the output using hook_form_alter and the Form API's #after_build, all you need is a custom module.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check for a particular content type's node form.

  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form') {
    // Add an after_build function to process when everything's complete.
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_after_build';
  }
}

function YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  /**
   * Override the output of options which start at 1.
   * 0 is the "none selected" element (if it's a required field)-
   * Replace the text formatted just as it would be in the options textarea.
   * This will properly display the less than character.
   */

  $form['YOUR_FIELD']['und']['#options'][1] = '1|small (<100)';
  $form['YOUR_FIELD']['und']['#options'][2] = '2|small (<200)';

  return $form;
}
```